# Infinite "Signal 11 being dropped" loop with Valgrind while trying to add to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

I'm trying to create a simple singly linked list in C, and have encountered an infinite "Singal 11 being dropped" loop while running my program in Valgrind.

My .h file:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

struct fruit {
    char name[20];
};

struct node {
    struct fruit * data;
    struct node * next;
};

struct list {
    struct node * header;
    unsigned count;
};

#endif
```

My .c file:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void init_list(struct list my_list)
{
    my_list.header = NULL;
    my_list.count = 0;
}

void add_to_list(struct list my_list, struct fruit my_fruit)
{
    struct node my_node;
    struct node nav_node;

    my_node.data = &my_fruit;
    my_node.next = NULL;

    if(my_list.count == 0) {    /* set head node if list is empty */
        my_list.header = &my_node;
        my_list.count++;
    } else {
        nav_node = *my_list.header;

        while (nav_node.next != NULL) { /* traverse list until end */
            nav_node = *nav_node.next;
        }

        nav_node.next = &my_node;

        my_list.count++;
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct fruit fruit_array[5];
    struct list fruit_list;
    int i;

    strcpy(fruit_array[0].name, "Apple");
    strcpy(fruit_array[1].name, "Mango");
    strcpy(fruit_array[2].name, "Banana");
    strcpy(fruit_array[3].name, "Pear");
    strcpy(fruit_array[4].name, "Orange");

    init_list(fruit_list);

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        add_to_list(fruit_list, fruit_array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming the issue stems from my list traversal in `add_to_list`, but I'm unsure about what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're passing structs by value into functions. This will create a copy of the struct in the function, and changes to the copy will not occur on the struct in the calling function.

You should read about pointers in your favorite c-language book.